# The shift+W+spacebar not working, even replace the keyboard , but the keyboard works on another PC

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, keyboard

I use Logitech K120 to play game, use i for 6 years and one day it cant press Shift + W + Spacebar for a sametime. So i think this is keyboard fault then i buy a new one recently.

But the issue still be exists. But i put 2 keyboard in another computer, it working perfectly !

I change the USB port of the PC but it's not helping
Only combination of Shift + W + Spacebar not works, i can use Shift + Spacebar + A,S,D,F is so fine.

I go to Control panel and Setting of windows and check all the keyboard option, it is so fine, i uncheck sticky key control in Ease of Access Center, etc.. but nothing changed.

Tested with the software named Aquakeytest.And it shown the spacebar not pressed when i put the combine keys with Shift+W+Spacebar

I think this a problem of windows, i use Windows 8.1 Pro and even update it in the last version.

So can anybody can help ?

Comment: 1)has Shift + W + Spacebar worked in the past on this PC? 2) I think you may have software running in the background that is grabbing/stealing the keystrokes, I'd try a clean boot: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd

Comment: Yes, it worked it the past. How do i try a clean boot ?

Comment: @AnhVuNguyen, see the link that gregg sent in his comment on how to do a Clean Boot

Comment: Ok i have done a clean boot but it cant be fix. The problem still exist